# TestFX: Test if TextArea contains a certrain text after entering it

Tags: java, unit-testing, testfx

I would like to test whether a TextArea has this text after entering a certain text. I use the following code, but get an error message.

Test Code:

```
this.clickOn("#descriptionTextArea").write("Text");
verifyThat("#descriptionTextArea", TextInputControlMatchers.hasText("Text"));
```

Error message:

```
Expected: TextInputControl has text "Text"
     but: was <ValidationTextArea[id=descriptionTextArea, styleClass=text-input text-area]>
```

The Control `ValidationTextArea` is a TextArea with some more functions.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed by updating the TestFX library to version `4.0.14-alpha`.